# How to write Persian (or Arabic) in a data frame?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a data frame including two vectors. The first vector is a vector of Persian names, and the second vector is a vector of numbers. My code is as follows:

```
A<-data.frame(x=c("مریم","ماریا"),y=c(1,1))
A
```

But when I run these codes I do not receive my desired output. Indeed the column of x is not in Persian. The output is like this:

```
                         x                 y
1         <U+0645><U+0631><U+06CC><U+0645> 1
2 <U+0645><U+0627><U+0631><U+06CC><U+0627> 1
```

I want to have the column of x in **Persian language**. Could you please help me how I can do it?

(I should say when I make a vector of Persian names and I run it, I receive the correct output in Persian, like below:

```
x=c("مریم","ماریا")
x
[1] "مریم"  "ماریا"
```

But in regard to the dataframe I have the above problem)

Comment: Please check the encoding (as it works for me)

Comment: @akrun,What do you mean by "encoding"? What I have to do exactly for solving my problem?